# Making inner static class top level

Tags: java, android, static-members

im implementing parsing of google's directions result into Java model classes.

```
HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
HttpResponse httpResponse = request.execute();
DirectionsResult directionsResult=httpResponse.parseAs(DirectionsResult.class);

...

 public static class DirectionsResult {
    @Key
    public List<Route> routes;
}

public static class Route {
    @Key
    public List<Leg> legs;
}

public static class Leg {
    @Key
    public Distance distance;

    @Key
    public Duration duration;

}

public static class Distance
{
    @Key
    public String text;
}

public static class Duration
{
    @Key
    public String text;
}


  ...
```

To acess data i can then use:

```
  Log.d(TAG,"directions result distance text: "+directionsResult.routes.get(0).legs.get(0).distance.text);
```

My question is how to create separate top level class called DirectionsResult and acess its member variables?

I tried mimicking static class behaviour of top class but with no sucess, was getting error ...

Answer (score 0):

You create a new Java file DirectionResults.java.  You copy the class in exactly as is, removing the keyword static from the line that declares the class.  Add the normal package line and any needed imports.  That's all you should need to do.

```
 public class DirectionsResult {
    @Key
    public List<Route> routes;
 }
```

Comment: Or just click on the class name and press F6 to move.

Comment: Assuming he uses the same IDE as you.  And that its the same hotkey in the version he uses

Comment: Yes assuming he uses the only IDE supported by Google and hasn't remapped the keys somehow. Pretty sure they are the same on all platforms.

Comment: And when eclipse was the only IDE supported I knew an awful lot of devs who used IntelliJ.  Now I know an awful lot who use Eclipse and Visual Studio.  Its a bad assumption.

Answer (score 0):

@Gabe Sechan: I already tried that and im getting the following error:

```
03-12 20:04:14.159 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key value
03-12 20:04:14.159 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:880)
03-12 20:04:14.163 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:381)
03-12 20:04:14.163 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:354)
03-12 20:04:14.163 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:87)
03-12 20:04:14.163 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
03-12 20:04:14.163 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
03-12 20:04:14.163 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.rootcave.roadpal.ride.createRide.CreateRideInteractorImpl$DirectionsFetcher.doInBackground(CreateRideInteractorImpl.java:231)
03-12 20:04:14.163 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.rootcave.roadpal.ride.createRide.CreateRideInteractorImpl$DirectionsFetcher.doInBackground(CreateRideInteractorImpl.java:189)
03-12 20:04:14.163 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-12 20:04:14.163 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-12 20:04:14.163 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-12 20:04:14.163 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-12 20:04:14.163 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-12 20:04:14.163 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-12 20:04:14.163 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-12 20:04:14.163 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key value, field public java.util.List com.rootcave.roadpal.ride.createRide.DirectionsResultModel.routes
03-12 20:04:14.163 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:880)
03-12 20:04:14.167 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:471)
03-12 20:04:14.167 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:780)
03-12 20:04:14.167 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:   ... 14 more
03-12 20:04:14.167 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key value, field public java.util.List com.rootcave.roadpal.ride.createRide.DirectionsResultModel.routes
03-12 20:04:14.171 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:880)
03-12 20:04:14.171 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseArray(JsonParser.java:647)
03-12 20:04:14.171 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:739)
03-12 20:04:14.171 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:   ... 16 more
03-12 20:04:14.171 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key value, field public java.util.List com.rootcave.roadpal.ride.createRide.DirectionsResultModel$Route.legs
03-12 20:04:14.175 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:880)
03-12 20:04:14.175 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:471)
03-12 20:04:14.175 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:780)
03-12 20:04:14.175 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:   ... 18 more
03-12 20:04:14.175 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key value, field public java.util.List com.rootcave.roadpal.ride.createRide.DirectionsResultModel$Route.legs
03-12 20:04:14.175 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:880)
03-12 20:04:14.175 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseArray(JsonParser.java:647)
03-12 20:04:14.175 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:739)
03-12 20:04:14.175 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:   ... 20 more
03-12 20:04:14.175 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key value, field public com.rootcave.roadpal.ride.createRide.DirectionsResultModel$Distance com.rootcave.roadpal.ride.createRide.DirectionsResultModel$Leg.distance
03-12 20:04:14.179 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:880)
03-12 20:04:14.179 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:471)
03-12 20:04:14.179 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:780)
03-12 20:04:14.179 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:   ... 22 more
03-12 20:04:14.179 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key value, field public java.lang.String com.rootcave.roadpal.ride.createRide.DirectionsResultModel$Distance.value
03-12 20:04:14.179 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:880)
03-12 20:04:14.179 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:471)
03-12 20:04:14.179 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:780)
03-12 20:04:14.179 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:   ... 24 more
03-12 20:04:14.179 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected numeric type but got class java.lang.String
03-12 20:04:14.179 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:843)
03-12 20:04:14.183 12525-12917/com.rootcave.roadpal W/System.err:   ... 26 more
```

Error happens in this line:

```
DirectionsResultModel directionsResultModel = httpResponse.parseAs(DirectionsResultModel.class);
```

This is json response im trying to parse, im interested in travel distance and travel duration fields:

```
http response parse as string: {
                                                                 "geocoded_waypoints" : [
                                                                    {
                                                                       "geocoder_status" : "OK",
                                                                       "place_id" : "ChIJhQEXk8ZXY0cRUnc0gzfpLX0",
                                                                       "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                       "geocoder_status" : "OK",
                                                                       "place_id" : "ChIJj7jA0mL6YUcRhAf0Exw-MhI",
                                                                       "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
                                                                    }
                                                                 ],
                                                                 "routes" : [
                                                                    {
                                                                       "bounds" : {
                                                                          "northeast" : {
                                                                             "lat" : 45.3581754,
                                                                             "lng" : 15.543227
                                                                          },
                                                                          "southwest" : {
                                                                             "lat" : 44.118924,
                                                                             "lng" : 14.2724169
                                                                          }
                                                                       },
                                                                       "copyrights" : "Map data ©2016 Google",
                                                                       "legs" : [
                                                                          {
                                                                             "distance" : {
                                                                                "text" : "243 km",
                                                                                "value" : 243413
                                                                             },
                                                                             "duration" : {
                                                                                "text" : "4 hours 2 mins",
                                                                                "value" : 14529
                                                                             },
                                                                             "end_address" : "Zadar, Croatia",
                                                                             "end_location" : {
                                                                                "lat" : 44.117578,
                                                                                "lng" : 15.219711
                                                                             },
                                                                             "start_address" : "Lovran, Croatia",
                                                                             "start_location" : {
                                                                                "lat" : 45.2969573,
                                                                                "lng" : 14.2724169
                                                                             },
                                                                             "steps" : [
                                                                                {
                                                                                   "distance" : {
                                                                                      "text" : "0.1 km",
                                                                                      "value" : 136
                                                                                   },
                                                                                   "duration" : {
                                                                                      "text" : "1 min",
                                                                                      "value" : 28
                                                                                   },
                                                                                   "end_location" : {
                                                                                      "lat" : 45.2961227,
                                                                                      "lng" : 14.2724438
                                                                                   },
                                                                                   "html_instructions" : "Head \u003cb\u003esoutheast\u003c/b\u003e on \u003cb\u003eLokva ul.\u003c/b\u003e",
                                                                                   "polyline" : {
                                                                                      "points" : "_ansGsqbvADGb@i@P[DYBE?AHGH?LBHDXp@Zv@"
                                                                                   },
                                                                                   "start_location" : {
                                                                                      "lat" : 45.2969573,
                                                                                      "lng" : 14.2724169
                                                                                   },
                                                                                   "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                                                                                },
                                                                                {
                                                                                   "distance" : {
                                                                                      "text" : "66 m",
                                                                                      "value" : 66
                                                                                   },
                                                                                   "duration" : {
                                                                                      "text" : "1 min",
                                                                                      "value" : 18
                                                                                   },
                                                                                   "end_location" : {
                                                                                      "lat" : 45.2956534,
                                                                                      "lng" : 14.2729462
                                                                                   },
                                                                                   "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e toward \u003cb\u003eUl. dr. Nilo cara\u003c/b\u003e",
                                                                                   "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                                                                                   "polyline" : {
                                                                                      "points" : "w{msGwqbvA@CTYXc@RQVQ"
                                                                                   },
                                                                                   "start_location" : {
                                                                                      "lat" : 45.2961227,
                                                                                      "lng" : 14.2724438
                                                                                   },
                                                                                   "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                                                                                },
                                                                                {
                                                                                   "distance" : {
                                                                                      "text" : "0.7 km",
                                                                                      "value" : 671
                                                                                   },
                                                                                   "duration" : {
                                                                                      "text" : "2 mins",
                                                                                      "value" : 144
                                                                                   },
                                                                                   "end_location" : {
                                                                                      "lat" : 45.2968208,
                                                                                      "lng" : 14.2758713
                                                                                   },
                                                                                   "html_instructions" : "Turn \u003cb\u003eleft\u003c/b\u003e onto \u003cb\u003eUl. dr. Nilo cara\u003c/b\u003e",
                                                                                   "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                                                                                   "polyline" : {
                                                                                      "points" : "yxmsG}tbvAE]AO@[BW?SAYCQCIIOOOOEaAGUCsACi@EUEKIGKCKAO?OBSHMHKPKp@MdAOdB]|A[LKBK@E?KAIQ
```

Edit: im using android studio

Edit:
It was really simple mistake, this is final look of the class:

```
public class DirectionsResultModel {
@Key("routes")
private List<Route> routes;

public List<Route> getRoutes() {
    return routes;
}

public static class Route {
    @Key("legs")
    private List<Leg> legs;

    public List<Leg> getLegs() {return legs;}
}

public static class Leg {
    @Key("distance")
    private Distance distance;

    @Key("duration")
    private Duration duration;

    public Distance getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }
    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

}

public static class Distance {
    @Key
    private String text;
    @Key
    private int value;

    public int getValue() {return value;}
    public String getText() {return text;}
}

public static class Duration {
    @Key
    private String text;
    @Key
    private int value;

    public String getText() {return text;}
    public int getValue() {return value;}

}
}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: I haven't inspected the JSON but it's saying one of those fields is defined as a number in the Java model and it's a non-numeric string in the JSON.

Comment: yeah i added string fields value in Distance class and in Duration class and they should  been int's and because of that error happened.It was really simple mistake, ive should have been inspecting error log more closely. Thank you all